# Is it good practice to access req.query in a PUT request?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, next.js, fetch

I'm building a website with an API using NEXTjs. For a single element, I use the dynamic api route provided by NEXTjs and I'm currently using that route both for getting an element and updating element.

In both the GET and PUT request, I use the req.query.fetchId to get or update the element.

However, I see req.query mostly used for GET requests and in POST/PUT request it's usually req.body being used.

It seems to work, but I'm wondering if I should?

This is the URL for the request: api/items/[fetchId]

And this is my code for the PUT request so far:

```
if (req.method==="PUT") {
    try {
      const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
      const videoGamesCollection = db.collection("videogames");
      const result = await videoGamesCollection
        .updateOne({ _id: ObjectId(req.query.fetchId) }, {$inc: {}})
      res.status(200).json({ message: "success", result: result });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(error.code ?? 502).send({
        message: error.message ?? "Something went wrong.",
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with a `POST` / `PUT` request to a URL with query parameters. I'd be more inclined to use [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) though

Comment: I would recommend to use patch instead PUT, As PUT is a method of modifying resource where the client sends data that updates the entire resource .  and PATCH is a method of modifying resources where the client sends partial data that is to be updated without modifying the entire data. Again depends on requirement.